Foundation 6 Responsive Menu not functioning as expected. What do I need to change to make it work?
First, the source code:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html class="no-js" lang="en-US">
    <head>
    <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8" />
    <meta name='robots' content='max-image-preview:large' />
<link rel='stylesheet' id='foundation-css' href='https://cdn.jsdelivr.netnpm/foundation-sites@6.8.1/dist/css/foundation.min.css' type='text/css' media='all' />
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery.min.js?ver=3.7.1" id="jquery-core-js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="http://example.com/wp-includes/js/jquery/jquery-migrate.min.js?ver=3.4.1" id="jquery-migrate-js"></script>
      
</head>
<body class="home blog">

    <ul class="vertical medium-horizontal menu" data-responsive-menu="drilldown medium-dropdown">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Item 1</a>
        <ul class="vertical menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Item 1A</a>
            <ul class="vertical menu">
              <li><a href="#">Item 1A</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 1B</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 1C</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 1D</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 1E</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1B</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <ul class="vertical menu">
          <li><a href="#">Item 2A</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2B</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Item 3</a>
        <ul class="vertical menu">
          <li><a href="#">Item 3A</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3B</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

        <script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/foundation-sites@6.7.4/dist/js/foundation.min.js?ver=6.7.4" id="theme-js"></script>
    <script>
        (function($){
            $(document).foundation();
        })(jQuery);
    </script>
</body>
</html>

As you can see, Foundation 6.8.1 and jQuery 3.7.1 have been added. I've initialised Foundation and I know it's working as the responsive menu is gaining a data-mutate attribute.
<ul class="vertical medium-horizontal menu" data-responsive-menu="drilldown medium-dropdown" data-mutate="4vsm9h-responsive-menu">
      <li>
        <a href="#">Item 1</a>
        <ul class="vertical menu">
          <li>
            <a href="#">Item 1A</a>
            <ul class="vertical menu">
              <li><a href="#">Item 1A</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 1B</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 1C</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 1D</a></li>
              <li><a href="#">Item 1E</a></li>
            </ul>
          </li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 1B</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Item 2</a>
        <ul class="vertical menu">
          <li><a href="#">Item 2A</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 2B</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
      <li>
        <a href="#">Item 3</a>
        <ul class="vertical menu">
          <li><a href="#">Item 3A</a></li>
          <li><a href="#">Item 3B</a></li>
        </ul>
      </li>
    </ul>

However, it's not adding the dropdown classes or the data-dropdown-menu attribute.
I've tried using different versions of Foundation that I've used in past projects where the responsive menu worked as expected. I've also tried initialising a straight dropdown menu, i.e. data-dropdown-menu, and that also mutates without adding any of the classes to the elements. I'm sure I must be missing something obvious, but I'm just not seeing what could be wrong with it.

After much back and forth, I've figured it out. The stylesheet controls the breakpoints for the JS media queries. The responsive menu plugin can't work without the breakpoints.
In previous compilations of my scss, I was missing @include foundation-global-styles which contains the media queries. I switched my stylesheet URL to a precompiled stylesheet to see if it was my assets that was the issue or the HTML.
However, there was a typo in the JSDeliver stylesheet URL which meant my JS still couldn't get the breakpoints for the menu. I'm not sure why that didn't flag as an error in the console, but it is what it is.
